# Не собирается шаблонный проект CUDA 8.0 в VS15

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda

Доброго времени суток! Порядок моих действий:

1. поставил CUDA Toolkit
2. поставил NVIDIA Nsight Visual Studio Edition
3. обновил драйвера(и на удивление Nsight)
4. обновил VS15 до Update 3

Создал проект по шаблону CUDA 8.0
[image: шаблон CUDA 8.0]
и при попытке его собрать получаю ошибку:

```
1>------ Сборка начата: проект: test, Конфигурация: Debug x64 ------
1>  Compiling CUDA source file kernel.cu...
1>
1>  C:\test\test>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2015 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64"  -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Leak Detector\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\include"  -G   --keep-dir x64\Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static  -g   -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /FS /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -o x64\Debug\kernel.cu.obj "C:\test\test\kernel.cu"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 8.0.targets(687,9): error MSB3721: выход из команды ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2015 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64"  -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Leak Detector\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\include"  -G   --keep-dir x64\Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static  -g   -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /FS /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -o x64\Debug\kernel.cu.obj "C:\test\test\kernel.cu"" с кодом "1".
========== Сборка: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========
```

В проекте ничего не изменял. Никак не могу разобраться, где я повернул не туда.

Comment: Выполните эту команду к консоли, посмотрите что оно пишет за ошибку.

Answer (score 1):

Прежде всего нужно понимать, как собирается CUDA приложение. Файлы с расширением *.cpp обрабатываются компилятором MS C++ (cl.exe), а файлы c расширением *.cu компилятором CUDA (nvcc.exe), который в свою очередь определяет, какой код будет работать на GPU, а какой на CPU. Код из *.cu, работающий на CPU, передается на компиляцию MS C++, эту особенность удобно использовать для написания динамических библиотек, которые будут экспортировать функции, использующие для расчетов GPU.

Далее привожу листинг простой программы на CUDA, который выводит на экран информацию об аппаратных возможностях GPU.

```
//FileName: cudaInfo.cu

#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

int main()
{
  int deviceCount;
  cudaDeviceProp deviceProp;

  //Сколько устройств CUDA установлено на PC.
  cudaGetDeviceCount(&deviceCount);

  printf("Device count: %d\n\n", deviceCount);

  for (int i = 0; i < deviceCount; i++)
  {
    //Получаем информацию об устройстве
    cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProp, i);

    //Выводим иформацию об устройстве
    printf("Device name: %s\n", deviceProp.name);
    printf("Total global memory: %d\n", deviceProp.totalGlobalMem);
    printf("Shared memory per block: %d\n", deviceProp.sharedMemPerBlock);
    printf("Registers per block: %d\n", deviceProp.regsPerBlock);
    printf("Warp size: %d\n", deviceProp.warpSize);
    printf("Memory pitch: %d\n", deviceProp.memPitch);
    printf("Max threads per block: %d\n", deviceProp.maxThreadsPerBlock);

    printf("Max threads dimensions: x = %d, y = %d, z = %d\n",
      deviceProp.maxThreadsDim[0],
      deviceProp.maxThreadsDim[1],
      deviceProp.maxThreadsDim[2]);

    printf("Max grid size: x = %d, y = %d, z = %d\n", 
      deviceProp.maxGridSize[0], 
      deviceProp.maxGridSize[1], 
      deviceProp.maxGridSize[2]); 

    printf("Clock rate: %d\n", deviceProp.clockRate);
    printf("Total constant memory: %d\n", deviceProp.totalConstMem); 
    printf("Compute capability: %d.%d\n", deviceProp.major, deviceProp.minor);
    printf("Texture alignment: %d\n", deviceProp.textureAlignment);
    printf("Device overlap: %d\n", deviceProp.deviceOverlap);
    printf("Multiprocessor count: %d\n", deviceProp.multiProcessorCount);

    printf("Kernel execution timeout enabled: %s\n",
      deviceProp.kernelExecTimeoutEnabled ? "true" : "false");
  }

  return 0;
}

* This source code was highlighted with Source Code Highlighter.
```

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, но в процессе поиска решения своей проблемы я ее уже почерпнул. К сожалению, ваш пример конечно же не собирается, по той же самой причине.